# c++ calculations are un-understandable

Tags: c++, calculation

I am little bit aware of c++ type conversions in calculation.
But unable to understand following code output.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    double a = 11.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1;
    double b = 12.0;
    std::cout << (a == b) << std::endl; // output : 0
    std::cout << (a - b) << std::endl; // output : -1.77636e-15
    return 0;
}
```

Why this code giving that output?
If you know, let me know. :>
And please also suggest some technics to handle it.

Comment: Watch [Computerphile : Floating point numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) it is fun to watch and you will learn something :). Floating point numbers are NOT (always) exact and there will be small errors. So this has nothing to do with conversions, it has to do with approximate representation of real numbers by a finite set of bits

Comment: are there actually any conversions?

Comment: No, there are no implicit type conversions in this code...

Comment: Nothing to do with type conversions (there are none). Instead it has to do with the inaccuracy of floating point arithmetic, something that affects every language that uses floating point arithmetic (which is basically all of them).

Comment: `double a = 11.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1`.   Consider the fact that NO floating point representation (with a binary aka base-2 significand - which describes almost all real-world floating point representations) can exactly represent the decimal value `0.1`.   Instead, a representable value *close* to `0.1` is stored (i.e. there is an error) and, when doing multiple operations (like addition) such errors propagate as well.

Comment: `int i = 1/3; i *= 3;` -- the value of `i` is 0, and most folks aren't surprised by that because they get how integer math works. The same thing happens with floating-point arithmetic: `double x = 1.0/3.0; x *= 3.0;` the value of `x` is not 1.0. (If you do this on a calculator it will lie to you; set it to show more precision and you'll see the truth). Numbers in computers have a fixed, finite number of bits; they cannot represent all possible numeric values, so the results you see don't match what you're used to  from pencil and paper calculations.

Comment: `11.7` is actually an approximation for `11.699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875` (on my machine), and `0.1` is an approximation for `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` (on my machine).  From that, it should be obvious why they don't equal `12.0`.

Comment: *And please also suggest some technics to handle it.* -- Don't use floating point variables.  Get a library or write your own code to use exact math, i.e. fixed point math and/or arbitary precision math.

Comment: ....and, even if you do use fixed point math or arbitrary precision math, there are still some values that can't be exactly represented. Some values (like "one third" in decimal,or the square root of two, or pi) have an infinite representation (versus finite, if large, limits on what a computer circuit can represent) so some rounding must occur in those cases. The usual approach is to design/select an algorithm (and representation) to suit a problem at hand, and mitigate [which is not the same as "eliminate"] the effects of things like rounding errors for that situation. Easier said than done.

Comment: Or take a university course in numerical methods and really understand how small errors with floating point numbers behave in calculations(and propagate).  Or  read about how floating point comparisson operations can be written: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: @Peter yup your last remark is what numerical methods are all about ;)

Comment: @OP Don't dispair, the most common approach is to compare to "almost" equality. In other words is the absolute difference between two values smaller than a given limit you consider them equal. It is just that comparing for exact equality almost never works with floating points.

Comment: @PepijnKramer   Indeed.

Comment: If those values represent monetary values, then either use integer, get a library that handles monetary calculations, or use a language designed to handle these types of values exactly, i.e. COBOL.  Many financial institiutions forbid using floating point variables in their programs, all due to the issue that floating point brings.

Comment: thought I better add to this question. but it could possibly be the way you assign values to each variable. here is my example of the same code.                                                              
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a = 11.7;
    a += (0.1)*3;
    double b = 12.0;
    double c = 11.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1;
    std::cout << (a==b) << std::endl;   // 1
    std::cout << (c==b) << std::endl;   // 0
    std::cout << (a-b) << std::endl;    // 0
    std::cout << (c-b) << std::endl;    // -1.77636e-15
    return 0;
}